# SQLite Selecting the first row who has a NULL in a column and changing that column to a different value

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, rowid

Hello I have a somewhat unique problem I need to select the first row that has NULL in the Status column and change its value to the text (processing)

To clarify I will use SQLite in a program that will need to process entries in a database.
The columns are
URL
Name
Status

The Name and URL is not something that I can control.
The Status column is used for the program all new entries come in with a NULL value I need to mark the first one with the text (processing) and then the program will refer to the row that has a value of (processing) in the status column and after it finishes change it to [FINISHED]

Also I don't want to select any row that also has NULL in the URL column.

I tried this code only its not getting me anywhere

```
SELECT * FROM List WHERE Status IS NULL ORDER BY ROWID ASC LIMIT 1
update List set Status = replace ( Status, NULL ,'(processing)')
commit;
```

What I definitively don't want to do is change all NULL values in the column Status at the same time. Only the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE List 
SET Status = '(processing)'
WHERE rowid = (SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM List WHERE Status IS NULL)
```

If you want also this condition:

> Also I don't want to select any row that also has NULL in the URL
> column.

then:

```
UPDATE List 
SET Status = '(processing)'
WHERE rowid = (SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM List WHERE Status IS NULL)
  AND URL IS NOT NULL
```

or:

```
UPDATE List 
SET Status = '(processing)'
WHERE rowid = (SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM List WHERE Status IS NULL AND URL IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: I struggled to make the code you presented work, yet I can not, can you write the full statement that I needed to do this task ?

Comment: @Enigma What do you mean by *full statement*? Each of my queries is a full statement. If you *can't make it work* then this means that you did not explain correctly your problem. Edit your question with sample data and expected results to clarify what you want. Better use a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27 for your data.

Comment: The command gives me errors and executes nothing. Sample data https://pastebin.com/xGzNi9DT

Comment: @Enigma as you can see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b45d68f037469503e79d4efcd7d74a54 all queries are syntactically correct. If you get errors this means that you are doing something wrong.

Comment: The statement doesn't execute anything on the DB.
I get an error on UPDATE.

Comment: @Enigma As I said. Either you did not clearly explain what you want or you are doing something wrong with my code.

Comment: "Either you did not clearly explain" what exactly is your code going to do ? Can you execute it on the sample DB I have given ?

Comment: @Enigma what sample db?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xGzNi9DT

Comment: @Enigma https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5b403f43e8396d124918a08da12d1a5c

Comment: Thanks it works. I think I got confused when you wrote "You need a WHERE clause in the UPDATE statement:" and tried to frankenstain your code into my code.